# Select any column with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Is it possible that the user could select any column of a table and that I could make it possible with jQuery?

I have the example here to play: http://jsbin.com/oluyex/1/edit

jQUERY. I don't know how to select the children of each th:

```
$(function(){
    $("th").click(function(){
        $(this).("children").css("background-color","red"); 
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<table id="taula" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you meant by *children of each th*

Comment: There are no children of any `th` in your example...

Comment: @jrummell I think he means the cells that are under that `<th>`, basically the column.

Comment: I want that if the user clicks to Header 1, this and row1,cell1 and row2,cell2 be selected. The same to any other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this all you need to do is get the index of the table header and then use that index to apply the class to each table cell in the column. You'll have to loop through each row to find the appropriate table cell. - http://jsfiddle.net/BMGKv/

```
$('th').click(function() {
    var th_index = $(this).index();
    $('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').eq(th_index).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is very good option. Would it be possible to select the th too and de-select the others columns when I click to any th?

Comment: It seems that option looses the toggle. Is it possible to : If I click to th de-select the others. And when I clic to a selected it de-selects

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("th").click(function(){
      var idx = $(this).index()+1;
      $(this).parent().siblings().find("td").css("background-color","white");
      $(this).parent().siblings().find("td:nth-child("+idx+")").css("background-color","red");  
    });
})
```

Test [here](http://jsbin.com/oluyex/5)

Comment: I don't understand this: nth-child("+idx+"), can you explain, please

Comment: It selects the child of <td> element having index equal to the index of clicked header of a table.

Comment: This is really good. Thank you. Is it possible to select the th too and have a toggle? I mean if I click to a th that is selected de-select it.

Answer (score 1):

The other `th` are not children in the DOM even though they are visually below the header.  You should improve your understanding of the tree data structure.

In any case, HTML tables are row-centric, so you have to select each table cell in the corresponding column more or less manually:

```
$("th").on('click', function () {
   $(this).closest('table').find('tr').find('td:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')')
      .css('background-color', 'red');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VFWBN/

EDIT: With nth-child, you can skip the `.find('tr')`: http://jsfiddle.net/VFWBN/1/

Comment: I am trying to understand it. When the user click I am trying to select the th too, de-select the columns. I try to toggle too I mean de-select the column when I click to a column that already has the red

Comment: Just toggle a class that has `background-color: red`